# Change text color to white

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Based on the code below, how can I change the text color to `white`? The code is adapted from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75558326/put-urls-in-separate-lines-different-spacing-and-appropriate-colors). In the tagged question answer, I don't know how the color was set to blue in the fist place.

```css
.footer-background {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #1c2a48;
}

.logo,
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-6MXa8B6uaO18Hid6blRMetEIoPqHf7Ux1tnyIQdpt9qI5OACx7C+O3IVTr98vwGnlcg0LOLa02i9Y1HpVhlfiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="footer-background container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/opengovernment/prr/Pages/default.aspx">Public Records Request</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/AgenciesAndServices/Pages/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/ReportAComplaint/Pages/Default.aspx">Report a Complaint</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspx">Terms of Use</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspxx">Accessiblity Statement</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://lp.constantcontactpages.com/su/ErJFVZz/B">Subscribe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="https://b.granicus.com/ViewPublisher.php?view_id=15">Watch Meetings</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Pages/Welcome.aspx">Copyrights 2022, Government</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-white" style="padding-top: 3rem; text-align: center;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add color: #fff;

Comment: add this  in your css : `.footer-background a { color : white; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add class css :

```
a{
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: remove the dot, **a** is a **tag** not a __class__.

Comment: Actually, `a` is an _element type_. Tags are just text in a file.

Answer (score 2):

text color is blue because its a `link` wrapped in `<a>` tag. to change the color of link text just add following style to anchor tag.

```
a{
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

and you can change the color of text as if the link is visited on not.

```
a:visited{
  color:red /* your fav color */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be an easy fix. You can apply the `color` to apply white color on the text. If you want to apply the color to the tag, use the CSS selectors    `:link` for unvisited links and `:visited` for the visited link.

Comment: Can you please explain this in the code? Thank you!